# JSON.stringify equivalent in Golang for map[string]interface{}

Tags: javascript, json, go

I'm new to Golang. I have to stringify a `map[string]interface{}` in Golang as you would do a `JSON.stringify` in javascript. In javascript keys which has their values `undefined` gets omitted when you do `JSON.stringify` and I want the same thing when I do `json.Marshal` in Golang for `nil` values. For e.g. in javascript

```
var activity = {"isvalid": true, "value": {"prop": undefined}, "prop": undefined}
console.log(JSON.stringify(activity)) 
// Output: {"isvalid":true,"value":{}}
```

But in Golang if I do this

```
activity := map[string]interface{}{
    "isvalid": true, 
    "value": map[string]interface{}{"prop": nil},
    "prop": nil,
}
jsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(activity)
fmt.Println(string(jsonStr)) 
// output: {"isvalid":true,"prop":null,"value":{"prop":null}}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dvmz32phdNU

There is a difference in output, what is a good way to make the output same in Golang as of Javascript?

**EDIT:**

The use case involves getting data from various sources which are of type `map[string]interface{}` and keys can be arbitrary, so converting it into a struct is not an option for me.

Comment: As Go has no notion of "undefined": No you cannot do what you want.

Comment: Use a struct with omitempty tag option. https://play.golang.org/p/l99KEcjU2az

Comment: If you cant use struct, recursively look for nils and remove those keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/KeeU7eagWh6

Define your variable as a struct and mark how each field should be marshalled into a json.
There is an omit tag that can be used to ignore nil fields. Refer to the example provided

Since OP has mentioned he cannot use structs, one other way is to recursively go through the map and remove entries where the value is nil.

https://play.golang.org/p/PWd9fpWrKZH

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "isvalid": true, 
        "value": map[string]interface{}{"prop": nil},
        "prop": nil,
    }    
    final := removeNils(data)
    out, err := json.Marshal(final)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}

func removeNils(initialMap map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    withoutNils := map[string]interface{}{}
    for key, value := range initialMap {
        _, ok := value.(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            value = removeNils(value.(map[string]interface{}))
            withoutNils[key] = value
            continue
        }
        if value != nil {
            withoutNils[key] = value
        }
    }
    return withoutNils
}
```